# My CI controller is not sending email or loading the success page

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, controller

I am new here, but I have this problem, the controller was working fine a few days ago and poof now nothing. It should send email the reg but it isn't working...

```
class Cs extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('cs');

    }

    public function apply() {

        $data = $this->input->post();

        if ($data) {


            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->from('mail@mail.com', 'name');
            $this->email->to('mail@mail.com'); 
            $this->email->subject('Nova prijava za FGL takmicenje - COUNTER STRIKE');
            $this->email->message(
                "Tim: " . $data['teamname'] . 
                "Clanovi tima:

                1. Ime i prezime:" . $data['ime1'] . ", nickname: " . $data['nick1'] . ", email: " . $data['email1'] . ", JMBG: " . $data['jmbg1'] . " 
                2. Ime i prezime:" . $data['ime2'] . ", nickname: " . $data['nick2'] . ", email: " . $data['email2'] . ", JMBG: " . $data['jmbg2'] . " 
                3. Ime i prezime:" . $data['ime3'] . ", nickname: " . $data['nick3'] . ", email: " . $data['email3'] . ", JMBG: " . $data['jmbg3'] . " 
                4. Ime i prezime:" . $data['ime4'] . ", nickname: " . $data['nick4'] . ", email: " . $data['email4'] . ", JMBG: " . $data['jmbg4'] . " 
                5. Ime i prezime:" . $data['ime5'] . ", nickname: " . $data['nick5'] . ", email: " . $data['email5'] . ", JMBG: " . $data['jmbg5']);    

            $this->email->send();

            redirect('/cs/success');

        }
        else {
            redirect('/');
        }

    }

    public function success()
    {
        $this->load->view('success');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about "isn't working"...

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable OpenSSL extension in your `php.ini` file?

Go to the directory where PHP is installed, and open php.ini and remove `;` in

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```